# VB.NET Using BackgroundWorker to prevent UI freeze - alternatives?

Tags: vb.net, user-interface, backgroundworker, freeze

I've just started a similar thread, but I feel this is a separate question, so here goes!

I'm using a BackgroundWorker to prevent my UI locking up while I perform a number of file operations.  While this has solved the problem, it's created another as the function the BackgroundWorker is called from needs to return a true/false based on the outcome of the BackgroundWorker.

Obviously, there's ways around this - using a loop to check if the worker is busy, but this seems to be a particularly kludge-y way of doing things.  I've done some further reading into this, and a lot of people say that if I need to wait until the BackgroundWorker is finished, I'm defeating the purpose of using it in the first place.

What are my options here?  Is there a 'correct' way to use a BackgroundWorker within a function and still have it report a return value based on the outcome of the work the BackgroundWorker is doing, or is there a simpler way to keep my UI responsive while other stuff is going on?

Answer (score -1):

Set `BackgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = True` when starting up your BackgroundWorker.

Call `BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress` in your `DoWork` method, and handle the `BackgroundWorker.ProgressChanged` event in your main thread.

Comment: I've already got that in place, but my code looks something like this:
`code`
Public Function DoStuff() as Boolean
    BWorker.RunWorkerAsync()
    'return true if BWorker worked, false if something broke
End Function
`code`
So I need the DoStuff function to return true or false based on the outcome of the BackgroundWorker.

Comment: For that, just handle `BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted` in your main thread and check the value of `e.Cancelled`. To set the value, just use `e.Cancel = True` in `DoWork` if the long process fails.

Comment: Otherwise you could try the new Async/Await features of VB2012 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx